# WPF : MvvmLight, Usercontrol, Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm-light, dependency-properties

I have a simple usercontrol (DoubleRadioControl2), composed of 2 radio buttons. I have a Dep Prop on this UC : (bool?)IsOuiChecked :

- true - 'yes' radio checked
- false - 'no' radio checked
- null - both
  radios unchecked

Pretty simple.

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty IsOuiCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsOuiChecked", typeof(bool?), typeof(DoubleRadioControl2), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

public bool? IsOuiChecked
{
    get
    {
        return (bool)GetValue(IsOuiCheckedProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(IsOuiCheckedProperty, value);
        if (value == null)
        {
            RadioYes.IsChecked = false;
            RadioNo.IsChecked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            RadioYes.IsChecked = (bool) value;
            RadioNo.IsChecked = !(bool) value;
        }
    }
}
```

And the logic between ths 2 radios :

```
private void OptDecompteConfnOui_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsOuiChecked = true;
    }

private void OptDecompteConfnNon_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsOuiChecked = false;
    }
```

When i bind this UC to my viewmodel, the prop binded if updated when i click on my radios. But when i set the value in the code of my view model, it won't update my radios.

In my viewmodel :

```
    private bool? _isDRB2OuiChecked;
    public bool? IsDRB2OuiChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return _isDRB2OuiChecked;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_isDRB2OuiChecked == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _isDRB2OuiChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsDRB2OuiChecked);
        }
    }
```

TwoWay binding not working.

Comment: Besides the answers below, you should also use `SetCurrentValue` instead of `SetValue` if you want to keep bindings on the dependency property intact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The getters and setters for your dependency property only exist for *your* (the programmers) convenience. WPF itself will not call them, but set the property directly.

You need to attach a handler to the changed event of the property. Use one of the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` constructors, that take a [PropertyChangedCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) . Your getter and setter logic needs to be handled there instead of inside the property.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVVM you should call OnPropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is a very **BAD** practice to put code inside the Get/Set parts of a dependency property, look at these exanples to get the solution. If you have the logic on DP changes, you have to put that login inside the callback.

1. Dependency properties explanation [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html).
2. MSDN Overview [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752914(v=vs.100).aspx).

if there is binding defined at the View/Viewmodel level you have to use a INotifyPropertyChange event at the Viewmodel side to inform View that the binded property was changed.

regards,

Comment: Thanks for the advice, makes sens.